# Is it possible to lock a table for insert of selected values

Tags: mysql

I want to lock a table so that no other thread can insert any rows with (e.g.) user_id = 5. while other thread is working on those set of rows. 
Though I can lock the full table but that seems too much and would reduce concurrency.

My thread does following and there are many of them running at a time.

```
Start Transaction
1) insert row with user_id=val
2) if (count (*) >= 2) where user_id = val and some other conditions then do "something"
COMMIT
```

Now if 2 threads run in parallel then it is possible that both of them get count(*) = 1 but when both of them commits the total row count is 2 which should have done that "something"

What I thought was that I need to lock the rows with user_id=val in each transaction so that nobody can even insert for user_id = val until my transaction completes.

Is there any way to achieve this using MySQL and Hibernate.

Comment: Do you mean `if (count (*) >= 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use locking reads.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE user_id = val FOR UPDATE.

will lock the matching rows until the end of transaction.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: There may not be a row when each of the transactions start.

Comment: That case should be covered by gap locks.

Comment: Wow, did not know about that.. very cool.. This is probably better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider simulating record locks with `GET_LOCK()`;

Choose a name specific to the rows you want locking. e.g. `'xxx_user_id_y'`. Where `'xxx'` is a string specific to the procedure or to inserts on this table and `'y'` is the user id.

Call `SELECT GET_LOCK('xxx_user_id_y',30)` to lock the name `'xxx_user_id_y'`.. it will return 1 and set the lock if the name becomes available, or return 0 if the lock is not available after 30 seconds (the second parameter is the timeout).

Use `SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('xxx_user_id_y')` when you are finished.

Be aware; You will have to use the same names in each transaction that you want to wait and calling `GET_LOCK()` again in a transaction will release the previously set lock.

[**`GET_LOCK()` docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)